# how to get openfire Subscription "to" roster status?

Tags: xmpp, openfire

folks

There is one question.

For example, A and B user in openfire server. A user have B user(Subscription "from") on his roster and B user have A user(Subscription "to") on his roster.

B user could know the current status of A user, but A user could not know the B user current state.

How can know A user the status of B users?

Answer (score 1):

When you get roster list, the list will come with its subscription.

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="5234:sendIQ" to="pqr@xyz.com">
<query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster">
    <item jid="abc@xyx.com" name="abc" subscription="from">
    <item jid="efg@xyx.com" name="abc" subscription="to">
    <item jid="def@xyx.com" name="abc" subscription="both">
</query>
```

so by programing you can differentiate and get subscription what you want.

Comment: I want to know Presence.Show(dnd, chat, away, xa) Type.